# Android default spinner list selection color changing randomly

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner, android-drawable

I am trying to implement a drop down list in Android.

Here is the `Spinner` which I am using in my layout.xml

```
       <Spinner
           android:scrollbars="vertical"
           android:id="@+id/spinner1"
           android:layout_width="125dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:prompt="@string/Category"
           
           />
```

In `MainActivity.java`, I am using the following code,

```
spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,category_items);
spinner_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(year_adapter);
```

Here is my **spinner_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
              android:layout_width="180dp"
              android:layout_height="40dp"
              android:textSize="18sp"         
              android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text_color"
              android:background="@drawable/selector_background"
              android:gravity="center"/>
```

**selector_text_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >            
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#F8BB00"/>    
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#F8BB00"/>        
   <item android:state_focused="false" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
   <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
   <item android:color="#F8BB00"/>  
</selector>
```

**selector_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="0dp"
    >
    <solid android:color="#3F4040"/>
    <corners 
    android:radius="8dp"
    />
</shape>
```

But, sometimes, spinner list item selection color is getting changed.
[image]
[image]

I don't know when it would show properly. Randomly the selection colors are getting changed.
Sometimes the selection is shown as 1st image and sometimes it is shown as 2nd image.

Why would this happen?
How to solve this?

Comment: Were you able to fix it? How?

Comment: No. I gave up. No one was able to answer . I think it's because of some Android SDK level issue..